# SpringBoot as WAR doesn't load/initialize Spring Config for Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, keycloak

I have a SpringBoot 2.3.1 application build with maven that loads some configuration from a `application.yml` in `src/main/resources`.

As a JAR the configuration is loaded from `<jarfile>/BOOT-INF/classes/application.yml`.

As a WAR the configuration is not loaded (null), but the WAR contains it in `<warfile>/WEB-INF/classes/application.yml`

My relevant dependencies are:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

and the profile is release.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <properties>
        <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I've tested that with

```
/** Main Entry Point for this Application */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    log.info("Configure Servlet");
    return builder.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

And a config class like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@KeycloakConfiguration
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  private String name;
  @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
  private String realm;

  /** Set Keycloak Config Resolver to use Spring Config */
  @Bean
  public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    log.error("1-spring.application.name is: " + name);
    log.error("1-keycloak.realm is: " + realm);
    KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver resolver = new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    return resolver;
  }

  @Bean(name = "MyTEST1")
  String getString() {
    log.error("2-spring.application.name is: " + name);
    log.error("2-keycloak.realm is: " + realm);
    return "Hello world";
  }
```

In the log message, I can see during startup that the realm and name is `null` in `keycloakConfigResolver()` method but milliseconds later not null in `getString()`. The `2-` logs are directly after the `1-..` logs in my log file.

```
2020-06-18 15:14:58.438 DEBUG 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.selfservices.platform.Application    : Running with Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.7.RELEASE
2020-06-18 15:14:58.440  INFO 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.selfservices.platform.Application    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-18 15:14:59.711  INFO 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1233 ms
2020-06-18 15:15:00.192 ERROR 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.s.platform.SecurityConfig            : 1-spring.application.name is: null
2020-06-18 15:15:00.192 ERROR 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.s.platform.SecurityConfig            : 1-keycloak.realm is: null
2020-06-18 15:15:00.664  INFO 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@167c9b7e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4c7dee5, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@43d8836e, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@2d74b982, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@2d74b982, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@1d951d12, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@1d951d12, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@13256bad, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4f27b99b, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@2839e57e, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@41fb5754, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@149db72c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@49d41456, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2aa4e85a]
2020-06-18 15:15:00.683 ERROR 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.s.platform.SecurityConfig            : 2-spring.application.name is: Plattform
2020-06-18 15:15:00.683 ERROR 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.s.platform.SecurityConfig            : 2-keycloak.realm is: myrealm
2020-06-18 15:15:00.931  INFO 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-18 15:15:01.170  INFO 14536 --- [alina-utility-2] d.m.selfservices.platform.Application    : Started Application in 3.277 seconds (JVM running for 1431.91)
```

I can confirm that behaviour on Tomcat 9.0.36, Wildfly 20 and with Spring Boot 2.2.6 and Keycloak 9.0.3 and 10.0.2. With embedded Tomcat everything is fine. When I intentionally misspell `keycloak.realm`, I'm getting correctly an exception, that the value could not be resolved.

So, the properties are there, I can reach them with a simple bean definition, but during keycloakConfigResolver() it isn't available. I'm aware of the "new" - but that is the example from Keycloak.

What do I miss?

Comment: Check if `snakeyaml-xx.jar` is present in classpath. It should come with `spring-boot-starter`. Still just to make sure.

Comment: yes, it is in the war as `snakeyaml-1.26.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the problem here is creation of the `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver` via "new".

The resolver has an internal `AdapterConfig` object. As part of some refactoring/bugfixing this object became non-`static` some time ago. Before the change the `static AdapterConfig` has been set centrally and all instances (constructed via new) could access that object. So this seems to be a bug within spring-keycloak.

The root cause here is, that `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver` should have been created by Spring itself and the `AdapterConfig` should have been declared an `@Autowired` field (or been set via constructor).

Two possible solutions come to mind.

1. Create your own `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver` (really not much code in there) using `@Autowired` on the `AdapterConfig` field (The injection will be done by Spring once your `keycloakConfigResolver()` annotated method returns the instance
2. Set the `AdapterConfig` via reflection within your `keycloakConfigResolver()` method